# Update using case in two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to use the query below in an update in order to update the first and last name. What's the best option to do that?

```
SELECT  
person.fullName,
(CASE WHEN 0 = CHARINDEX(' ', person.fullName) 
    then  person.fullName 
    ELSE SUBSTRING(person.fullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', person.fullName)) end) as first_name,  
(CASE WHEN 0 = CHARINDEX(' ', person.fullName) 
    THEN ''  
    ELSE SUBSTRING(person.fullName,CHARINDEX(' ', person.fullName), LEN(person.fullName) )end) last_name
FROM person
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is database. Oracle??

Comment: are you using this query to update some values in another table? or in the same table?

Comment: sorry sql server 2008 and same table

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this code, i did not modify your condition , but showing you the logic to use your code to update first and last name. I assume the table has FirstName and LastName columns

```
UPDATE Person
SET
Person.FirstName =
(CASE WHEN 0 = CHARINDEX(' ', person.fullName) 
    then  person.fullName 
    ELSE SUBSTRING(person.fullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', person.fullName)) end)       ,  
Person.LastName =
(CASE WHEN 0 = CHARINDEX(' ', person.fullName) 
    THEN ''  
    ELSE SUBSTRING(person.fullName,CHARINDEX(' ', person.fullName), LEN(person.fullName) )end)
FROM person
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly :)